# Incomplete information in stack trace in Firebase Crashlytics NDK?

Tags: android, crashlytics, oboe

I’ve just added **Firebase Crashlytics NDK** to my **Android** project. I need it as I’m using **Oboe** (the C++ library for high-performance audio).
I’ve followed all the steps in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports), and I’m able to see the issues in Firebase Crashlytics when I make my app crash.
The problem is that I’m unable to know from the stack trace provided by Crashlytics where the problem is in my code. I know the crash comes from another method in another class (both created by me and in the same folder as OboeMetronomePlayer.cpp) that gets called from `OboeMetronomePlayer::startMe()`, but that method and class are not indicated anywhere in the stack trace, so if this was a real crash I wouldn’t be able to track it down.
In contrast, in the stack trace provided by the **Logcat** of **Android Studio** I see the method where the exception is triggered, the class and the error message that would allow me to much better track the issue.

[image: Stack trace]

Am I missing anything?
Is there any way to improve this stack trace in **Firebase Crashlytics** or do I have to resort to other tools?

Thanks!